# Reasons 10BASE2 network is not functioning

Tags: networking

I'm new to this forum, and I want to ask a question.

I'm writing my CS homework, and our lecturer asked us to list reasons for 10BASE2 network to not function.

So far I found these reasons:

- because coaxial cabling is used to implement bus topology networks, a fault could bring down the entire network
- The two ends of a 10Base2 bus must be properly terminated. If they are not, signals will bounce and network communications will be impossible.

Can someone tell me more reasons?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell your lecturer not to waste your time with a network technology no one's seen since 1995.

Answer (score 0):

- Putting in any extension/cable between the T-connector and the BNC-connector on the network card will cause your network either NOT to work or becomes unreliable.

If one of the systems is located away from the cable, you CANNOT use a drop-cable from the t-connector to the BNC of the Network Card (NIC) It either does NOT work or works unreliable.

- Using other cable impedance than 50 ohms will not work.

Answer (score 0):

- Too long cable (without repeaters)
- Bad cable-to-conector contact (as they are connected only by pressure)